# MITx: 6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python

Tags: python

So I'm very new to Python... The problem is as follows:

**Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month.**

My current code is as follows:

```
month = 1
minimumMonthlyPayment = (balance * monthlyPaymentRate)
totalPaid = 0.0

while month < 13:
    print "Month: " + str(month)
    print "Minimum Monthly Payment: " + str(round(minimumMonthlyPayment, 2))
    balance = (balance - (balance * monthlyPaymentRate)) * (1 + (annualInterestRate/12))
    minimumMonthlyPayment = (balance * monthlyPaymentRate)
    print "Remaining Balance: " + str(round(balance, 2))
    totalPaid += minimumMonthlyPayment
    month += 1

print "Total Paid: " + str(round(totalPaid, 2))
print "Remaining Balance: " + str(round(balance, 2))
```

Here's the correct output:

[image: Correct Output]

So all the numbers are identical in both outputs but my Total Paid ends up being 1732.94 instead of the correct amount which is 1775.55. I added the numbers from my output up on a side calculator and it came out to 1775.55 as well. Is there something in my code that's borking this?

Here are the values for the variables that the test code uses:

```
balance = 4213;
annualInterestRate = 0.2;
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04;
```

Comment: Please post code that can be copy pasted

Answer (score 1):

You are recalculating your balance before calculating your `minimumMonthlyPayment` rate.

So `balance * monthlyPaymentRate` comes to a different amount on line 8 and 9 since balance has changed.

If you assign `balance * monthlyPaymentRate` to a variable before those lines and use it for both calculations it would correct this.

Comment: Excellent advice! Thank you, Alex, it worked instantly!

Answer (score 1):

Great job! Your code is almost perfect. The only mistake is that line 8 needs to run before line 9. You're changing the balance and then using that changed balance to calculate the minimum monthly payment. You need to calculate the minimum monthly payment for each month before you update the balance.

Hope this helps!

---

```
balance = 4213
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
totalPaid = 0.0

month = 1
minimumMonthlyPayment = balance * monthlyPaymentRate

while month < 13:
    print "Month: " + str(month)
    print "Minimum Monthly Payment: " + str(round(minimumMonthlyPayment, 2))
    minimumMonthlyPayment = balance * monthlyPaymentRate
    balance = (balance - (balance*monthlyPaymentRate))*(1+(annualInterestRate/12))
    print "Remaining Balance: " + str(round(balance, 2))
    totalPaid += minimumMonthlyPayment
    month += 1

print "Total Paid: " + str(round(totalPaid, 2))
print "Remaining Balance: " + str(round(balance, 2))
```